# can anyone help me finding alternative algorithm solution - without using sort()?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, big-o

```
function areSimilar(a, b){
    return a.sort().join('') === b.sort().join('');
 }

 console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])); //true
 console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3])); //true
 console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1])); //false
```

Two arrays are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the arrays.

Given two arrays a and b, check whether they are similar.

**Example**

- For a = [1, 2, 3] and b = [1, 2, 3], the output should be
  areSimilar(a, b) = true.

The arrays are equal, no need to swap any elements.

- For a = [1, 2, 3] and b = [2, 1, 3], the output should be
  areSimilar(a, b) = true.

We can obtain b from a by swapping 2 and 1 in b.

- For a = [1, 2, 2] and b = [2, 1, 1], the output should be
  areSimilar(a, b) = false.

Comment: *"Two arrays are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the arrays."* That isn't what your `areSimilar` function checks, unless your function is only ever called with three-element arrays...? For instance, it would return `true` for `[1, 1, 2, 2]` and `[2, 2, 1, 1]` but getting from the former to the latter requires two swaps, not just one.

Comment: Just about to post similar comment as T.J, your sort version wouldn't be doing what question asks,.  It's only giving the correct true / false only by accident based on the examples provided.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/meta-strings-check-two-strings-can-become-swap-one-string/

Comment: If I understand this right, my idea is to sort both arrays by values (it does not really matter by which 'algorithm', ascending, descending, by strings or with comparison). Once sorted, you can compare each corresponding positions (keys) and if you find more than 1 difference, result should return false.

Comment: @dev101 `If I understand this right`, Unfortunately your missing an important part of the questions -> `swapping at most one pair of elements`  sorting is most certainly going to break that rule.

Comment: Thanks @Keith, just realized that while coding!

Answer (score 3):

If i understand well, 2 arrays are "similar" if they contains the same elements and there's is not more than 2 differences (because if you have more than 2 differences, you can't just swap 2 elements and get the same array).

So i'll go for something like this :

```js
function areSimilar(a, b) {
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return false;
    }

    var differences = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
     if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
      differences.push(i);

      if (differences.length > 2) {
       return false;
      }
     }
    }

    if (!differences.length) {
     return true;
    }

    if (differences.length == 1) {
     return false;
    }

    return Math.abs(differences[0] - differences[1]) == 1 && a[differences[0]] === b[differences[1]] && a[differences[1]] === b[differences[0]];
}

console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])); //true
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3])); //true 
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1])); //false
console.log(areSimilar([2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2])); //false
```

Comment: this algorithm will return TRUE in this case: A = [2, 1, 1]; B = [1, 1, 2]; but 2 swap operations are required in A to make it equal to B.

Comment: Wait ? you allow to swap only neighbour elements ? It could be important to say it in the question

Comment: see comments after OPs question: *swapping at most one pair of elements*

Comment: I fixed the function

Comment: @dev101: I don't think "swap two elements" means "swaps two *adjacent* elements" but perhaps you should ask OP to clarify.

Comment: You still need 2 permutations to obtain [2,1,1] from [1,1,2] - correct?

Comment: No. You just swap index 0 with index 2. It's one permutation.

Comment: a[0] = 2, b[2] = 2. How will swapping 2 with 2 (values) achieve equality?

Comment: Do you know ES6 version of this solution?

Comment: Just replace the `var` by a `let`  and you have a compatible ES6 version. Maybe you can replace the for loop with a forEach but since you are comparing 2 arrays you'll have a messy code.

Comment: or: b[0] = 1, a[2] = 1, still no change.

Comment: @dev101 as i understand it, a swap is swapping 2 values. So `swap(a[0], b[2])` is only 1 swap.

Comment: Yes, no doubt about that.

Comment: @dev101: swapping two elements in *one of* the arrays. It's not swap(a[0], b[2]); it's swap(a[0], a[2]). Which gives you [1, 1, 2]

Comment: is there any es6 way? what if we use sort( ) does it cause Big O complexity?

Comment: @rici that makes sense, then! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version which works in O(n) time (it looks at each position exactly once) and O(1) time (no temporary containers; just scalars):

```js
function areSimilar(a, b) {
    /* Helper function:
     * Compares a and b starting at index i, and returns the first
     * index at which they differ. If there is no difference returns
     * max(i, a.length)
     */
    function nextDiff(i) {
        while (i < a.length && a[i] == b[i]) ++i;
        return i;
    }
    /* If lengths are different, obviously not similar */
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;
    diff1 = nextDiff(0);
    /* If there is no difference, they're the same (and thus similar) */
    if (diff1 >= a.length) return true;
    /* Find the second difference */
    diff2 = nextDiff(diff1 + 1);
    /* Similar if there is a second difference
       and a swap would produce equality
       and there is no further difference.
     */
    return diff2 < a.length
           && a[diff1] == b[diff2] && a[diff2] == b[diff1]
           && nextDiff(diff2 + 1) >= a.length;
}

console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])); //true  (identical)
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3])); //true  (single swap) 
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1])); //false (not permutation)
console.log(areSimilar([2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2])); //true  (single swap, not adjacent)
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1])); //false (permutation, needs two swaps)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count the items and take a `Map` for keeping track of the count.

```js
function areSimilar(a, b) {
    return a.length === b.length
        && b.every(
            (m => v => m.get(v) && m.set(v, m.get(v) - 1))
            (a.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map()))
        );
}

console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])); //  true
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3])); //  true
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1])); // false
```

Comment: This is very pretty but, like the incorrect code in the OP, it only checks that the two arrays are permutations of each other. It will return true given inputs `[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]`, which cannot be made identical with a single swap. Even so, +1 for a lovely example of fat arrows.

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of the answer: it will return false in case 2 or more swap operations are required.

The algorithm is very simple and easy to understand actually, albeit probably not optimal in terms of speed.

Debugging console logs are left for educational purposes, so you can see how it works! :)

```js
function areSimilar(a, b) {
  if (a.length != b.length) {
    return false;
  }

  let differences = 0;

  for (let i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // console.log('a[i] = ' + a[i]);
    // console.log('b[i] = ' + b[i]);
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
      differences++;
    }
  }

  // console.log('differences: ' + differences);

  // trivial case: arrays are identical
  if (differences == 0) {
    return true;
  }

  // we know that in this case no swap combination can return a == b
  if (differences == 1) {
    return false;
  }

  // clone a array into c array
  let c = a.slice(0);

  // set comparison variables
  let comparison = 0;
  let matchFound = 0;

  // only this case should be tested, because if difference is > 2 similarity fails according to initial condition
  if (differences == 2) {
    for (let j=0; j < a.length; j++) {
      for (let k=0; k < a.length; k++) {
        // re(set) temp variables
        c = a.slice(0);
        comparison = 0;
      //  console.log('a = ' + a);
      //  console.log('reset c = ' + c);
      //  console.log('reset comparison = ' + comparison);
        if (j !== k) {
          // swap array value pairs
          [ c[j], c[k] ] = [ c[k], c[j] ];
          // console.log('c[j' + j + '][k' + k + ']: ' + c);
          // compare arrays
          for (let n=0; n < c.length; n++) {
            if (b[n] !== c[n]) {
              // console.log('b[n] = ' + a[n]);
              // console.log('c[n] = ' + c[n]);
              comparison++;
              // console.log('comparison [' + n + '] = ' + comparison);
            }
          }

          if (comparison === 0) {
            matchFound = 1;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // evaluate final result
  if (matchFound === 1) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

// TEST ARRAYS

var a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [1, 2, 2, 4, 3];

// TEST FUNCTION

if (areSimilar(a, b)) {
  console.log('a & b are similar!');
} else {
  console.log('a & b are NOT similar!');
}

// OTHER 'COMMON' TESTS
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])); //true  (identical)
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3])); //true  (single swap) 
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1])); //false (not permutation)
console.log(areSimilar([2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2])); //true  (single swap, not adjacent)
console.log(areSimilar([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1])); //false (permutation, needs two swaps)
```